# CakePhp 3.0 unable to login

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I'm new to CakePhp framework and followed the blog tutorial.
Everything went smooth until authentication part.

The following two lines were the problem:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('Usuario') ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('Contraseña') ?>
```

The correct lines are:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('username') ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('password') ?>
```

This is my login method from UsersControllers.php, the debug line always returns false.

```
public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            debug($this->Auth->identify());
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Usuario o contraseña inválida, intente nuevamente'));
        }
    }
```

This is my user class
I had to change the line protected $_accessible = ['*' => true]; as appears in the tutorial, otherwise users wouldn't be saved.

```
class User extends Entity
{
    // Make all fields mass assignable for now.
    protected $_accessible = ['username' => true,'password'=>true,'role'=>true,'created'=>true,'modified'=>true];
    // ...
    protected function _setPassword($password)
    {
        return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
    }
    // ...
}
```

This is my login.ctp

```
<div class="users form">
    <?= $this->Flash->render('auth') ?>
    <?= $this->Form->create() ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Ingrese su usuario y contraseña') ?></legend>
        <?= $this->Form->input('Usuario') ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('Contraseña') ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Login')); ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

These are my AppController.php methods:

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'loginRedirect' => [
    'controller' => 'Expedientes',
    'action' => 'index'
    ],
    'logoutRedirect' => [
    'controller' => 'Pages',
    'action' => 'display',
    'home'
    ]
    ]);
}

public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
   $this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view']);
}
```

At this point I can add users, their passwords are hashed but I can't login.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long is your password field?

Comment: Hi, password varchar(255) utf8_general_ci

Comment: Ask yourself, how should the auth mechanism know that it should use the field `Usuario` for the username, and `Contraseña` for the password? Not to mention that the uppercasing violates the CakePHP naming conventions!

Comment: Please make this as an answer and accept it to help future readers

Comment: ^ I'm not sure this question could help someone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ndm for the answer. I translated username and password fields in the following lines:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('Usuario') ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('Contraseña') ?>
```

Correct lines are:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('username') ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('password ') ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, while setting your Auth componenent configurations, you can set which fields, in your db, serve as username and password

```
 $this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
        'Form' => [
                      'fields' => [
                                  'username'=>'email',
                                  'password' => 'password'
                              ],
                      'userModel' => 'Users'
                  ]
         ]);
```